# Where do I specify runtime IOC in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control

I am trying to figure out how to get runtime parameters setting using IOC setup in MVC4.

I have not selected an IOC framework yet and am happy to take suggestions.  I would prefer to avoid NInject, as I have heard that it is fairly slow.

I need to specify my IOC  After login.  So I am thinking that I need to create a FilterAction that will handle this.  Is this the best place to do the IOC or is there a better place?

I have seen a lot of IOC examples that do the  specification at design time and I but I could not find anything that made the IOC container via a filterAction or some other sort of  post-login event.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a useful article with some performance benchmarks for different IOC containers - you're right about NInject :) http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should write a custom `IDependencyResolver` your your favorite DI framework. This resolver will be used by ASP.NET MVC to inject dependencies into common structures such as controllers. And to avoid reinventing the wheels search for a DI framework which already has an MVC extension to id adding this dependency resolver (probably the NuGet package will be suffixed with `.MVC`, for example `Unity.Mvc3` or `Ninject.Mvc3`, ...). The container setup is then performed in your `Application_Start`.

Comment: I have done a lot of reading and everything I have seen implementing the IDependencyResolver has always been static implmentations....I am not sure when this is called by the MVC framework so I am not sure if I have access to cache data (i.e. session, cookies, etc)...

Comment: To finish...I have read about the IControllerActivator which is a way of specifying the dependency...but has access to the session and request information...but I have never seen an example of it being used....I am also interested in the IViewPageActivator as I would like to map dependencies for my views as well as my controllers....  I have decided to use NInject so any direction on where to look for information about how to do this (runtime dependency mapping of controllers and views would be helpful....